# recycler view is not displaying all my content fetched from api

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

**The below is my activity layout file**

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:background="#B71C1C"/>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progresslayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The below is my code for recycler row**

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"

    app:cardElevation="6dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#E91E63"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="3.3"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name of the file"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"

            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtQuote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtTitle"
            android:text="name_of_the_author"

            android:padding="8dp"

            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="19sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtQuoteid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="rs_299"
            android:padding="8dp"


            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtTitle"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**the issue is since for textquote text view I am fetching and trying to display large text content some contents are not getting displayed.how to fix this issue?.The size of recycler is fixed automatically based on the first content of first recycler view please help me**

**descactivitycode**

```
class descactivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var recyclerview: RecyclerView
lateinit var adapter: Horizontal_RecyclerView
lateinit var layoutmanager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
lateinit var progressLayout: RelativeLayout
lateinit var button: Button
lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
val bookInfoList = arrayListOf<Book>()
val ratingComparator = Comparator<Book> { book1, book2 ->
    book1.title.compareTo(book2.title, true)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_descactivity)


    recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar)
    layoutmanager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)


    progressLayout = findViewById(R.id.progresslayout)
    progressLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    val intent = intent
    val selectionOption = intent.getStringExtra("option")
    val selection = intent.getStringExtra("option1")
    if (selectionOption != null) {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "https://quotesapp-api.herokuapp.com/getquotes"
        if (ConnectionManager().checkConnectivity(this as Context)) {
            val JSONObjectRequest =
                object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener {
                    println("response is $it")

                    val success = it.getBoolean("success")
                    try {
                        if (success) {
                            progressLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                            val data = it.getJSONArray("data")
                            for (i in 0 until data.length()) {
                                val bookJsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i)
                                val BookObject = Book(
                                    bookJsonObject.getString("_id"),
                                    bookJsonObject.getString("title"),
                                    bookJsonObject.getString("quoteid"),
                                    bookJsonObject.getString("quote")
                                    //bookJsonObject.getInt("__v")


                                )
                                bookInfoList.add(BookObject)
                                adapter =
                                    Horizontal_RecyclerView(this as Context, bookInfoList)
                                recyclerview.adapter = adapter
                                recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutmanager
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "some unknown error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }


                }, Response.ErrorListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "volley error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    println("error is $it")


                }) {

                    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()

                        return headers
                    }

                }
            queue.add(JSONObjectRequest)

        }
    }
```

**adapter**

```
class Horizontal_RecyclerView(val context: Context, val itemList:ArrayList<Book>):RecyclerView.Adapter<Horizontal_RecyclerView.MyViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false)
    return MyViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val book=itemList[position]
    holder.txtTitle.text=book.title
    holder.txtQuote.text=book.quote
    holder.txtQuoteid.text=book.quoteid



}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return itemList.size
}
class MyViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val txtTitle: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)
    val txtQuote: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuote)

    val txtQuoteid: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuoteid)

   // val llcontent: LinearLayout =itemView.findViewById(R.id.llcontent )
}
```

}

Comment: can you please post your java/kotlin code here..?

Comment: @FlyingDutchman i have added code

Comment: Add your Horizontal_RecyclerView adapter code.

Comment: @AmarIlindra i have added.i feel something mistake in layout file only

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview doesn't seem to know its parent width and height very well. By the time I was using "match_parent" and "wrap_content" I had a misloaded activity/fragment.

What I finally did wasn't the smartest solution but worked for me. I'm calculating dip per screen and then calculate screen width dynamically, then setting my recycler view the amount that just worked for me `(width - 45*(scale))`. 45 is a number that I tested on different devices and decided is good enough. Once again it's not wisest, it's the only thing that has worked for me.

```
int pixel = 120;
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dip = (int) (pixel * scale + 0.5f);

WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int width = (windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
int width2 = (width - 45*(Math.round(scale)));
view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(width2, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: can u tell me how to use this code in kotlin

Comment: @kaarthikDeivasikamani Sultan Logic behind what I did is actually pretty easy. I don't know Kotlin but I have explained what to do. You can find with a little bit of search. I also remember that by the time I was searching for my problem, I saw Kotlin solutions too

Answer (score 0):

Hi there on the  recycler row XML file,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="3.3"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

try altering the layout_width from 290dp to wrap_content/
match_parent, then place the width limit on the main xml file.
**plus** on the **txtQuote TextView tag** inplace of padding switch to margin .

if it fails kindly reach out